# Scala play JSON for BigDecimal precision

Tags: scala, playframework

Anyone knows how to specify the precision of `BigDecimal` type when play JSON return the result?

For example, if the `BigDecimal` value is 100, how can I display as 100.00 when play JSON return the JSON value?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Play thing. Play Json is a wrapper (in my opinion a good one) over Jackson.

If you are trying to use this for money, which I suspect you do, do not apply rounding at serialization time since you may actually lose some money. Do it within your model! Working with money is a separate topic.

In case this is not related to money, you can apply a separate translator for that attribute.

As I said, what applies to Jackson can also be applicable to Play JSON. You might try to define a serializer for that attribute only.You should implement your own [JsonSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html), and annotate your attribute with `@JsonSerialize(using = <YourSerializer>.class)` .

Comment: I am using Scala Play not Java Play, I don't think annotation works for case class

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to provide an implementation of `writes` for your object that does the formatting (rounding) you are looking for, an example would be something like this:

```
case class Thing(a: String, b: BigDecimal)
object Thing {
    implicit val writes = new Writes[Thing] {
        def writes(t: Thing): JsObject = Json.obj(
            "a" -> t.a,
            "b" -> t.b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)    // Round here
        )
    }
}
```

Example:

```
val t = Thing("some string", 10.123456789)
val j = Json.toJson(t)
println(Json.prettyPrint(j))
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "a" : "some string",
  "b" : 10.12
}
```